# How to add SunJSSE security provider in a Websphere appserver

Tags: java, websphere, java-security

I'm trying to use a thirdparty JAR that has this code:

```
KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "SunJSSE");
```

While running the code in Websphere Application server, it fails with a

> java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: SunJSSE

The provider for **PKCS12** in the IBM world is **IBMJCE** Provider. Would replacing the entry for SunJSSE to **com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2** in java.security file work? Even if it does,  is that the best way to make this work?

Comment: Did you consider trying it before you posted?

Comment: I'm working in a restricted environment where I do not have write access to edit security file. I want to hear from people who have tried this. And the pitfalls in adding Oracle providers to IBM Appserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

> Would replacing the entry for SunJSSE to com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2 in java.security file work?

Yes.

> Even if it does, is that the best way to make this work?

No. The reason from IBM.

> 1. IBM does not support problems with Sun's or other third party JSSE or JCE code. Only the IBM JSSE and JCE providers are supported.
> 2. WebSphere supports the JSSE and JCE "provider framework", which means that multiple providers can be "plugged in". This means customers should be able to plug in Sun's (or other providers) JSSE or JCE into IBM's framework. If it cannot be plugged in to the framework, then IBM will investigate problems with the framework only.

Enforcing provider is a bad practice.Oracle docs say so
[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html)

> General purpose applications SHOULD NOT request cryptographic services from specific providers

```
getInstance("...", "SunJCE"); // not recommended
// ... versus ...
getInstance("..."); // recommended
```

The thirdparty jar I had problems with is opensourse So, I could raise a change and get the offending code replaced.